# Java -> operator

Tags: java, operators

I know that `->` is used for lambda expressions with the syntax `()->{}`.

But I saw this code: `file -> file.isFile()` - with no `()` and `{}`. What does it do?

Comment: shortcut for `(var file) -> { return  file.isFile(); }` || [JLS 15.27.1. Lambda Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1-120): "*If a lambda expression has exactly one formal parameter, and the parameter is specified by an identifier instead of a parameter specifier, then the parentheses around the identifier may be elided.*" and [JLS 15.27.2. Lambda Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2-100): "*A lambda body is either a single expression or a block (§14.2).*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`()` is not required when you have a single argument and `{}` is not required when your lambda body is a single expression.

See [the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) for further information and the [Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) for a more formal description of the syntax.

Comment: I understand, thank you! Is there a trick to understand how to expand those expressions?

Comment: What do you mean "expand"?

Comment: Write it as an actual function for more clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you please give an example? And by the way, I have a feeling that what you're asking is another question entirely that *could* deserve its own separate post.

Comment: Oh, you mean something like `file -> file.isFile()` vs something like `File::isFile`?

Comment: Little trick missing in the specification: when you need to invoke with parameters but you don't need to actually use the parameters, you can name them `__`. For example, `map.computeIfAbsent(key, __ -> new ArrayList<>()).add(something)`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca exactly!

Comment: @Math4me there's no trick :) it's called a method reference. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: @user16320675 nothing, I did a mistake (just tested and I couldn't do what I thought I could). So I removed the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

As Federico answered, for the *single arguments* you do not need `()` and for *the statements only return a value* and do not do anything else, you do not need `{}`.

The addition I want to make to his contribution:

The code you put means, there is a function, that takes file as a parameter. Then, returns its `.isFile()`.

In other words, you can also reach the same aim by defining a method:

```
<private/protected/public> boolean myLovelyMethod(File file){
    return file.isFile();
}
```

Lambda function just makes it a little bit shorter. If you are not going to re-use the method, may be better to use lambda.